# Error loading MongoDB Atlas Via Compass on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ubuntu-18.04

Recently downloaded MongoDB Compass for Ubuntu, then I copied the connection string from MongoDB Atlas for connecting using MongoDB Compass . When I opened the MongoDB Compass it detected a connection string which I accepted. I had to input my Username and password for a database,  I also made sure I gave it readWrite access,  then I set Authentication Database to admin. Then I clicked on the connect button, seems to be connected but I get this error :

`"An error occurred, while loading navigation:(Unauthorized) not authorized on adminto execute command {hostInfo: 1, $clusterTime: { clusterTime:{15968188 1}, signature:{hash:{0 [20 202 80 145 95 128 153 13 117 177 59 15 72 163 143 56 16 217 179 110]}, keyId: 6854717737982230528.0000000 }}, Isid: {4 [140 166 93 131 187 215 73 247 156 156 59 49 80 208 94 140]} } }".`

I know am connected to MongoDB because I was able to create new database from the compass application,  but I am unable to see my DBS and COLLECTIONS  from the compass application. [The screenshot of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcVJp.png)

Comment: Which documentation are you following?

Comment: Official MongoDB documentations.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my MongoDB Compass too, after reading this post.  Now it works again.  I'm using free tier MongoDB Atlas on Windows 64b with MongoDB Compass and it had just stopped working after two years.  So John Rossberg has the correct answer, and to add to the answer, the answer is that free tier quit working with older MongoDB Compass.  My old version was 1.14.6.  It's working again now with MongoDB Compass 1.22.1, with no modifications to the Atlas accounts.  MongoDB Compass 1.14.6 still throws the error.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by updating to the lastest version of MongoDB Compass